# Many datepickers in one table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net-core, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap 4 datetimepicker library https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/
I've got a table on my page and in each row there is one datepicker. And now, these datepickers are rendering correctly, but only first datepicker reacts on click (shows calendar), when the other ones don't react.
It is like my function points at only single datepicker's id, when it should stores something like Array Id's. I have no idea how to change this.

**HTML**

```
                <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.ViewModel.TrainingsList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" asp-for="@item.Id" value="@item.TrainingDate"/>
                                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                        <div class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
                                            <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

**JQuery**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            sideBySide: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `id` attributes have to be unique within the DOM. Duplicating them is invalid. Change the selector to a class and it will work. Eg. `$('.date').datetimepicker();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unique id for each date picker. 
Example :

```
<tr>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" asp-for="@item.Id" value="@item.TrainingDate" id="datetimepicker1"/>
                                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
                                        <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

And change the `data-target` and the `id` in each row like `datetimepicker2`, `datetimepicker3` 
And also change the jquery like follow.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1, #datetimepicker2, #datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
        sideBySide: true,
    });
});
```